# Incompatibility of Verse and Dialogue Packages?

Tags: verse, dialogue

I am trying to typeset a selection from a poem near the beginning of a document as well as typeset a portion of a dialogue later in the document. The verse package spins off an error (which various threads attribute to an incompatibility with the hyperref package) but if this is ignored the text typesets correctly. In my MWE, the error is still shown.

If you run the MWE adding the dialogue section (it's commented out in the MWE) the verse does not typeset properly--it is no longer centered. Strangely, two figures (braces) are added to the beginning of the verse text and there are several other errors. The dialogue section is properly typeset. Remove the dialogue section and the verse section compiles properly--no extra characters and properly centered.

I am using the bookest document class, but I ran the MWE through the Koma book class (scrbook) and got the same result. I am using Xelatex.

Also, the package bookest ignores the a5 papersize option, I'm not sure why. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a5,pagesize]{scrbook}%bookest  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}  
\usepackage{verse}  
%\usepackage{dialogue}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage{xunicode}  
\usepackage{xltxtra}  
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}  
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Palatino Linotype}  
\linespread{1.2}  


\usepackage{xunicode}  

\begin{document}  

Como dijo Tupac Shakur,  


\bigskip  
\settowidth{\versewidth}{la vida de delincuente}  
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]  
la vida de delincuente\\  
no la escogí\\  
la vida de delincuente\\*  
me escogió a mí  
\end{verse}  

%\begin{dialogue}  

%\speak{Menón} Sí, Sócrates, pero, cómo es que dices eso de que no aprendemos, sino que lo que denominamos aprender es la reminiscencia? Podrías enseñarme que es así?  

%\speak{Sócrates} Ya te dije poco antes, Menón, que eres difícil; ahora preguntas si puedo enseñarte yo, que estoy afirmando que no hay enseñanza, para hacerme en seguida caer en contradicción conmigo mismo.   

%\speak{Menón} No, por Dios, Sócrates! No le dije con esa intención, sino por costumbre. Pero, si de algun modo puedes mostrarme que en efecto es así como dics, muéstramelo.   
%\end{dialogue}  


\end{document}
```

Comment: `dialogue` redefines the `verse` environment; just switch the package order: first `dialogue`, then `verse`.

Comment: Changing the order fixes the problem with the verse package, but now the sc (small capitals) shapes for the speakers of the dialogue disappear. I tried several font packages to make sure that the packages selected had small cap glyphs.

Comment: Nesting a small caps command: \speak{textsc{Speaker}} doesn't work either.

Comment: I get small caps, but I don't have your Palatino Linotype, so I tried with TeX Gyre Pagella.

Comment: This is now working after moving the two packages back and forth several times. I don't have an explanation for this behavior.